# How to add background image to navigator in react-native-navigation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to add background image to navigator in react native navigation by Wix. Is that even possible?

[This is where I want to add the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeD1o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be implemented if you hide navigation bar and write your own custom bar. You can give it a bottom shadow too as mentioned in your design.

```
static navigatorStyle = {
   navBarHidden: true
};

const NavBar = (
  <View>
  // your content
  </View>
);
```

And in your render function, you can directly use it hiding native bar.

```
render() {
   return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         <NavBar />
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         // render your page content here
         </View>
      </View>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible, to achieve it you need to create your own Navigation bar and hide wix's one:

```
  static navigatorStyle = {
    navBarHidden: true,
  };
```

And then you can try writing your own:

```
return (
  <View
    style={[
      styles.navBar, // here you can pass image
      style,
      typeof renderRightContent === 'function' && styles.withRightButton,
    ]}
  >
    {typeof renderTitle === 'function' && renderTitle()}
    {!hideBackButton &&
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.backButton}
        onPress={onPress || (() => navigator.pop())}
      >
        {!hideBackArrow &&
          <Image source={require('../../assets/arrow_left_icon.png')} />}
        <Text style={styles.backTitle}>
          {leftTitle || I18n.t('common.backButton')}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>}
    {typeof renderRightContent === 'function' && renderRightContent()}
  </View>
);
```

Few days ago i wrote something like this